# Call to undefined relationship [competency] on model [App\Models\Summary]. Laravel 9

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables, **Summary** and **Competency**, I just met this error when I was trying to show foreign key data from **Competency** into table **Summary**.

Here is my Summary model:

```
class Summary extends Model
{
    protected $table = "summary";
    protected $primaryKey = "id";
    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'competency_id', 'price'
    ];

    public function competency_id()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Competency::class);
    }
}
```

Here is my Competency model:

```
class Competency extends Model
{
    protected $table = "competency";
    protected $primaryKey = "id";
    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'competency_name'
    ];

    public function summary()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Summary::class);
    }
}
```

My SummaryController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Summary;

class SummaryController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $summaryData = Summary::with('competency')->get();
        return view('dashboard', compact('summaryData'));
    }
}
```

My dashboard.blade.php

```
<tbody>
  @foreach ($summaryData as $item)
      <tr>
          <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
          <td>{{$item->competency->competency}}</td>
          <td>{{$item->price}}</td>
          <td>
          <a href="{{url('edits', $item->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
          <a href="{{route('delete', $item->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger" >Delete</a>
          </td>
      </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

I really appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model you declared the method name as:

```
public function competency_id
```

And when you called it with eager loading you did:

```
$summaryData = Summary::with('competency')->get();
```

You are trying to call `competency` relationship while it's name is `competency_id`. Just change the method name in your model to `competency` and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

You are calling wrong method name of relationship.

Your relationship method name is competency_id and you are calling it competency, which will throw error.

Either you change method name to competency or call is as below:

```
$summaryData = Summary::with('competency_id')->get();
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

in summary class you shave to

**replace**

```html
public function competency_id()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Competency::class);
    }
```

*to*

```html
public function competency()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Competency::class);
    }
```